# ROSSerializationException when publishing custom ROS message with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, ros

I am trying to publish a ROS message that uses a custom message that I created, OccupancyGrid3D:

```
std_msgs/Header header
MapMetaData info
  time map_load_time
  float32 resolution
  float32[] time_resolutions
  uint32 depth
  uint32 width
  uint32 height
  geometry_msgs/Pose origin
int8[] data
```

I am publishing it using this publisher:

```
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
self.pub_motion_prediction = rospy.Publisher("motion_prediction", numpy_msg(OccupancyGrid3D), queue_size=3)
```

And then later calling this:

```
def pub_3d_grid(self, velocities):
    grid = OccupancyGrid3D()
    grid.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    grid.header.frame_id = "map"
    grid.info.map_load_time = rospy.Time.now()
    grid.info.resolution = self.resolution
    grid.info.time_resolutions = velocities
    #grid.info.time_resolutions = np.array(velocities, dtype=np.float32)
    grid.info.depth = self.TIMES
    grid.info.width = self.shape_map[0]
    grid.info.height = self.shape_map[1]
    grid.info.origin.position.x = self.x0
    grid.info.origin.position.y = self.y0
    grid.info.origin.orientation.w = 1
    grid.data = np.minimum(100, self.probability_grid_3d.flatten().astype(np.int8), dtype=np.int8)
    self.pub_motion_prediction.publish(grid)
```

My subscriber, in a separate node, is as follows:

```
rospy.Subscriber("motion_prediction", numpy_msg(OccupancyGrid3D), self.callback, queue_size=3)
```

However, every time I run the node that has a listener for this topic I get the error: `ROSSerializationException: field data must be a list or tuple type`, which as far as I can tell means I am trying to publish a numpy array when ROS wants to just use a list. However I want to use a numpy array so that I can specify the data type. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the subscriber you are using?

Comment: @PierreC. I've added my subscriber to the best of my memory as I'm no longer at my work computer. I'm fairly certain I have it correct.

Comment: I have tested a little on my machine and I could only reproduce your error when I tried sending a 2D array. `flatten` should prevent that but, who knows, you might want to check what you actually put in your message with `np.minimum`.

Comment: Which version of ROS do you use? Hint: You get a serialization error, which is always caused by the publisher. Of course, serialization only happens when someone subscribes. I've tested your example with `OccupancyGrid` and explicit serialization [here](https://gist.github.com/tik0/6a1807799c34a0970cd0a6775af36177), and I couldn't reproduce your error. Please give a full working example of your publisher, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: I am using ROS Kinetic and my publisher is used only as shown above. Velocities is also an array, and strangely enough, when I cast it as a numpy array, the serialization error gets thrown there, when I make it a list instead, the error gets thrown at the last line as before, and when I take it out completely everything else works. I'm not sure why one numpy array would work but not both.

Comment: Also if this information helps, probability_grid_3d is an array with shape (10,304,204) with values between 0 and 100 and velocities is a list with 2 or three values in it.